# wordpress error after upgrading to version 3.5

Tags: php, wordpress

When I logged in to my wordpress admin page it showed me please upgrade to wordpress 3.5 , when I clicked upgrade it had been upgraded but i found the following php error

**Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in E:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-3.3-RC3\wp-content\plugins\wp-symposium\wp-symposium.php on line 1120 and defined in E:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-3.3-RC3\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 990**

please help me . I don't know how to solve this problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, it is not you who should solve that problem.

The problem is arising from [WP Symposium](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-symposium/) plugin's file. Do you have the latest version of the plugin installed? I haven't checked the plugin itself, but from the download page they say that the plugin is compatible upto WordPress Version 3.5

Answer (score 1):

That's because `prepare` should be used with a `?` placeholder for unverified arguments. Since version 3.5, Wordpress has decided to warn you if you misuse it.

Andrew Nacin (who was the lead developer for 3.5) announced this change [in a blog post on make.wordpress.com](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/):

> This wasn’t a decision done lightly. We don’t like shoving PHP warnings into the faces of users and developers. But given the potential security risks, we wanted everyone to immediately look at how they are running queries. And, of course, always prepare them properly.